# C#: Read line from file & determine if it contains a substring

Tags: c#

I am working on a program for personal use that will automatically sort a grocery list (from file) into a particular order. I want the program to open the file, read each line, and determine if each line contains certain words. For example, a line could contain "chicken breasts," and the program would just recognize that it contained "chicken." The idea is to have the program automatically order my list so that I'm not running back and forth getting items when I go to the store. Currently the external file line must have the exact text "chicken" for the program to recognize it ("chicken breasts" will not be recognized). Here is the section that I believe is giving me trouble:

```
if (groceries.Contains("chicken"))
                {
                    chicken = "Chicken";
                    lstItems.Items.Add(chicken);
                }
```

Groceries is an array with each element being a line from the file (I think I created it correctly). Below is the entire code:

```
private void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Grocery items
        string chicken;           
        
        //StreamReader variable
        StreamReader readFile;
        
        string filePath;

        //Counter variable
        int index = 0;

        //Display open file dialog box
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
                       
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Set filepath as a variable
            filePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            
            // Assign the file as a variable  
            readFile = File.OpenText(filePath);

            //Count lines in file and create array
            int lineCount = File.ReadLines(filePath).Count();
            string[] groceries = new string[lineCount];

            //Read file's contents
            while (index < groceries.Length && !readFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                groceries[index] = readFile.ReadLine();
                index++;

                if (groceries.Contains("chicken"))
                {
                    chicken = "Chicken";
                    //Display items in label
                    lstItems.Items.Add(chicken);
                }                                        
            }

            //Close file
            readFile.Close();
        }
    }
```

When the program is run, it will add "Chicken" to the listbox the same number of times as the number of lines in the file, even though only one line actually contains "chicken." My question is: How can I make it pick out the keyword from a longer line of text, and why is it adding the item more than once? Thanks!

***Edit***
(Sorry I don't know how to attach a file here)
I am currently importing a .txt file with the following data:

chicken
fish
Frosted Flakes cereal
pork tenderloin
ground beef

Comment: Could you provide a txt file demo to test?

Comment: you have a lot of points to improve, but your actual issue here `if (groceries[index].Contains("chicken"))`

Comment: The most important thing for you to do is [learn how to use a debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Comment: Does something like this help? `bool containsChicken = File.ReadLines("shopping_list.txt").Where(x => x.ToLower().Contains("chicken")).Any();`

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding any other problem or what the overall goal of the application is. You forgot to look at the actual line

```
if (groceries[index].Contains("chicken"))
```

It's worth a note that you should likely be using `File.ReadLines` or `File.ReadAllLines` instead. As it gives you a collection or enumerable to work with

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to remove the redundant `openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();`. And access the elements in groceries by index. Then add additional conditions to exclude rows that contain "chicken breasts". Note that `index++` is executed after the `if statement`.

```
//  define a varibale
bool chickenadded = false;

OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
// remove the redundant ShowDialog
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    // code omitted ...

    //Read file's contents
    while (index < groceries.Length && !readFile.EndOfStream)
    {
        groceries[index] = readFile.ReadLine();

        // check here
        if (groceries[index].Contains("chicken") && !chickenadded /*&& !groceries[index].Contains("chicken breasts")*/)
        {
            chicken = "Chicken";
            lstItems.Items.Add(chicken);
            // set to true
            chickenadded = true;

            // another way is not define boolean, just use "break"
            break;
        }
        // reset index here
        index++;
    }
```

Comment: What I actually want the program to do is to read any line that contains "chicken" as just "chicken." For example, "chicken breasts," "chicken wings," "chicken tenders" would all just be considered chicken (and only counted once). Ultimately I will have the program organize the items by where they are in my local store. Also, I don't know how to attach a file to the post, but I'll edit the post to include the data at the end.

Comment: @Tim If so, you only need to remove `&& !groceries[index].Contains("chicken breasts")` in `if statement`.

Comment: @Tim Do you mean that there are many lines contain "chicken" and you want only one "chicken" shown in `lstItems`? To achieve this, you can define a boolean variable to check if a "chicken" has been added. I have updated the answer. Or just add a `break` in `if statement`.

Comment: There could potentially be many lines containing different chicken items. Imagine if your significant other created a grocery list, and then you created a grocery list. They would likely not be exactly the same, so I want the program to be able to handle small differences (recognizing that "chicken" is the important term).

Comment: I get an exception when using the line '''if (groceries[index].Contains("chicken"))'''       The object reference is not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: `if (groceries[index].Contains("chicken"))`  Fixed formatting

Comment: @Tim Add a break point to check if the `groceries[index]` is null.